# Installed software back-up

Tags: backup, restore

I have Linux Mint 15 Mate installed on one PC and I am currently updating it and installing necessary language packs, software, etc. After full set up can I back-up the entire system and restore it on another PC running same version of Linux (Mint 15 Mate)? Or at least restore all updated files and software?

I am on limited Internet access and traffic is costly :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additional instructions:

When you install a package using a *package manager* (example `apt-get`) it first **checks if the version it wants to install is already downloaded** and in its cache directory. So if you copied the .deb packages and they are the newest version then it won't need to download them again. It's as simple as that.

Of course if you want to make sure both installs are the same you can use the list of installed packages

**Old machine:**

`dpkg -l | grep ^ii | awk '{print $2}' > mypackages.txt`

Now copy the `mypackages.txt` file to the other computer

**New machine:**

```
pkgs=$(cat mypackages.txt)
sudo apt-get install --no-download --show-upgraded $pkgs
```

You also may want to look into [apt-offline](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/Offline_Package_Management_for_APT). 
As far as `rsync` goes...

```
$ sudo -i
# apt-get install rsync openssh-server
# service start sshd
# ssh-keygen
# ssh-copy-id root@<machine-local-ip>

# rsync -av root@<machine-local-ip>:/var/cache/apt/archives/ /var/cache/apt/archives/
```

And then run the rsync line as a daily `cron job`.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I found another approach as well. I copied cached files from one PC to another one. I used backup utility to make list of all packages on first PC and then I used this list on second PC to restore. It worked nicely. So I have two PCs with similar packages and saved traffic as I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

There are two distinct approaches to this.

1. Either backup and restore the entire install on another machine.
2. Share the .deb packages between machines.

Advantages to cloning (option #1) include only having to do the configuration once. Disadvantages include copying the bootloader/MBR for different capacity disks can be tricky. In addition there are a plethora of articles detailing how to do that using various utilities.

I will instead detail option #2.

Linux Mint (and Ubuntu for now...) are Debian derivatives (technically the non-LMDE edition of Mint is based on Ubuntu). The point is, the package format is a **.deb** archive and the package manager is **apt-get** (or a GUI on top of it like "Software Center")

You simply need to intercept the .deb packages stored in `/var/cache/apt/archives/`.

Provided:

1. You don't use `apt-get clean` to delete the cached packages
2. Both machines are running the same distro (and version)
3. You aren't mixing and matching architectures

This should work quite nicely. You could set up `rsync` and share packages both ways over LAN too.

Comment: Exactly what I meant! All 3 provisions are met. So, it means I can just copy all packages stored in /var/cache/apt/archives/ from one PC to another. What command I need to run to install copied files on another PC? And what about rsync? How it works? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**On Linux Mint Mate**

I believe there is a tool for this called [Backup Tool](http://www.linuxidentity.com/us/down/articles/Backup_TBoL9_EN_www.pdf) that comes with Mint. You can use this for software selection backup.

**On All Debian**

To backup, on the old machine, I believe you can use:

`# sudo dpkg --get-selections > ~/backup/installed-software.log`

Copy the `installed-software.log` to the new machine.

And to restore:

`# dpkg --set-selections < ~/backup/installed-software.log`

followed by

`# dselect`